# Who verify certificate in openSSL

Tags: openssl, ssl-certificate

When i use openssl to create a certificate for my website,who must verify my certificate?
E.g : when you want login to yahoomail , your certificate verifies by DigiCert .

Comment: It is more suitable for serverfault.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Information to be put on the certificate is verified by the trusted Certificate Authority (CA) on which almost all the browsers trust.

To get a certificate from a trusted CA, you need to submit a certificate signing request. After verification, CA will issue a certificate.

And it is the browser or client of SSL who actually verifies the certificate on the basis of trusted certificate available with it.

Answer (score 1):

Certificate which you created using open ssl is not trusted certificate.Submit the file ending in .csr to a commercial SSL provider for signing. You will receive a signed file after the CA signs the request.

You can vist

```
https://www.thawte.com/roots/index.html
https://knowledge.verisign.com/support/ssl-certificates-support/index.html
```

for root certificates